# Contact form keeps giving error message to enter phone when phone is already entered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a contact form on certain pages of my site. If a user is not logged in, the form won't submit and says a phone number is required even if one is entered. But if someone is logged in, it works fine.

Here is the link to the JS: https://u.realgeeks.media/lookinwa/js/contactform.js

Here is a test page: https://www.bothellhomes.com/property/1574281/

Any clue is to why? It's been driving me nuts...

Comment: Hey man it's really hard to understand from that code and example, can u produse it with less and not compiled code? might be one of the reasons are "name" on form and the function that takes them from backend could expect something else?

Comment: Man, I don’t know where to start to simplify this error... there is another contact form on bothellhomes.com/member/contact that works perfect regardless if someone logs in or not to use it. Sorry that I am not of more help :/

Comment: I don't think we/or someone could fine this from here..

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling. Really hard to pinpoint why it’s doing this. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sure, again just control the backend's expectation about form properties and the one's you send from form =) Hope you can find soon

Comment: I looked at this and it appears as though the "phone" field in this form is not being accessed correctly somewhere.  When the "Contact Agent" button is pressed, the value of the "phone" is blank.  Here's what's being passed to the server when the "Contact Agent" button is pressed:   first_name=todd&last_name=smith&email=todd%40smith.com&message=I'm+interested+in+23930+1st+(Lot+3)+Ave+SE%2C+Bothell%2C+WA+98021%0A+%0A+Property+URL%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bothellhomes.com%2Fproperty%2F1574281%2F&how_soon=Not+Sure&recaptcha=&phone=

Comment: check your param when sent API. I have checked, the phone number param is empty that's why your system shows the warning. please check your code especially when get the phone number, is it correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this further and it looks like the issue is in your contactform.js file.  On the #contact-agent click event, each property is being saved off to be sent to the API.  The phone number is set as follows:

```
if ($('.rg-modal.rg-modal-contact .miranda-lb .lb-content input[name="phone"]') == '') {
$('.rg-modal.rg-modal-contact .miranda-lb .lb-content input[name="phone"]')['val']($('.property-form input[name="phone"]')['val']())
};
```

It may make more sense to set the phone number the same way the other fields in this method are set (without the check).  I would recommend commenting out this check (but not the assignment) to see if this works.

If nothing else, a few console.log in here may help determine what's going on.

Comment: Yeah it's still not working. I thought it was that early too. The console isn't helping really either. There is another JS file that runs the whole site, and I'm a newbie so not really deciphering that one too well.

Comment: I saw your comment and saw that it didn't work.  I was attempting to debug but it looks like you may be making other changes.  From what I see, when this form is submitted, all of the values in it are copied to another form and that form is submitted.  I would concentrate looking at the submit method of that form.

Comment: I didn't change, I changed something and changed it back. It's doing the same thing. If it helps, that form that it is copying from is when you click the contact us button a little below that. Your help is so appreciated.. so thank you.

Comment: It has to do with the formatted of the phone number on that contact form.  I'm looking at this in detail more now.

Comment: Really?! Thanks so much. Excited to see what you find.

Comment: I was trying to add the unmasked phone from your input into the masked input of the popup contact form and realized that the server is verifying that that input is in the correct phone number format. If I enter an invalid phone number format, the server returns **Phone numbers must be in (XXX) XXX - XXXX format.**.  Because of this, I'm going to suggest that you mask the phone number input on the "right hand contact form" so that it matches what the server is expecting.  Next, you may need to figure out how to set the val of the phone number field programmaically. Looks like "val" doesnt work.

Comment: I've been trying to mask the input all day, no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, this file contains everything for the other contact form. It's a huge file, but if you find something (and have the time) that would be greatly appreciated: https://www.bothellhomes.com/static/CACHE/js/aa292bf07375.js